# Make foreach create variable names depending on input? How to use extract()

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Is it possible to do this without having to type the entire thing?
Like with a foreach loop that generates the required variable names from the session variable names?

```
if (isset($_SESSION['MembershipForm'])) {
    $tempstore = $_SESSION['MembershipForm'];

    if (isset($tempstore['ref_referee'])) {
        $ref_referee = $tempstore['ref_referee'];
    } else {
        $ref_referee = NULL;
    }

    if (isset($tempstore['ref_address'])) {
        $ref_address = $tempstore['ref_address'];
    } else {
        $ref_address = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain in more details what are you trying to achieve??

Comment: Looks pretty obvious not? If the session array variable has a value for an array key then I want to assign that value to a new variable with a proper name. If the session does not have a value I want to set the value of the variable to NULL.

Comment: I'm only using 2 variables here, but my actual form has 20+ variables ...

Comment: still confused you can just get array of the `$_SESSION['MembershipForm']` and return it you won't also need to check `isset`

Comment: I'm assigning $ref_referee and the other variables to a field wether they are set or not, so they all need a value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use extract() function:

```
$tempstore = $_SESSION['MembershipForm'];
extract($tempstore);

echo $ref_referee;
```

Comment: That easy huh? :)

Answer (score 1):

Well... if I understand you correctly you have something like:

```
$_SESSION['MembershipForm'] = array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2'); // etc
```

And you want to create dynamic variables depending on the content of your array.

```
foreach($_SESSION['MembershipForm'] as $key => $value){
    ${$key} = $value;
    // this will create variables like this $key1 = 'value1'; etc
}
```